# How to run Windows phone 8 & 8.1 Unit tests in jenkins [Visual studio 2013]

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, jenkins, windows-phone-8.1

We use Jenkins as our CI, and im looking to have Jenkins run visual studio tests. Ive figured out how to have Jenkins use vstest.console.exe for desktop applications, but im not sure how to get that to work for windows phone 8.1 tests. I'm running vstest.console.exe against my unit test project's appx file, but im getting:

> Error: App package ...appx does not has test executor entry point. For
>   running unit tests for Windows Store apps, create app package using
>   Windows Store app Unit Test Library project.

Any help getting the program to work thorugh command line would be of big help, but if there is a short cut to run it through jenkins that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem. Make sure to use /InIsolation, and use  /Settings:{settingsFile}. For some reason vstest.console.exe cant run the unit tests for windows phone without specifically setting a settingsfile. In jenkins/vsTestrunner there is an option to set the settings file. You will likley still get an error regarding running the test in non-interactive way on jenkins, but there are a few stackoverflow posts about this already.